# Listview in Android while getting data from a server

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to populate the data into listview Asynchronously

I am retrieving data from server as JSON response

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // url to make request

    private static String url="http://54.218.73.244:7002/";

    ListView yourListView;

    List<Item> yourData = new ArrayList<Item>();

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);

        //Instantiating ProgressDialog with onCreate method
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        new ParsingAsync().execute();

    }

    private class ParsingAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please Wait", true, false);


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            //Create a JSON parser Instance ----- Used JSON parser from Android
            JSONObjParser jParser=new JSONObjParser();

            //Getting JSON string from URL ------ Used JSON Array from Android
            JSONArray json=jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            List<Item> yourData = new ArrayList<Item>();


            try {
                for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject c=json.getJSONObject(i);// Used JSON Object from Android

                    String RESTAURANT_NAME=c.getString("restaurantNAME");

                    yourData.add(new Item(RESTAURANT_NAME));

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.itemlistrow, yourData);
            yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        }   
    }
}
```

**JSONObjParser.java**

```
public class JSONObjParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONArray jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONObjParser() {

    }

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONArray(json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**log::**

```
08-23 20:43:59.442: W/dalvikvm(1311): threadid=6: spin on suspend #1 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
08-23 20:43:59.442: D/dalvikvm(1311): Temporarily moving tid 1320 to fg (was 0)
08-23 20:43:59.442: D/dalvikvm(1311): Temporarily raised priority on tid 1320 (10 -> 0)
08-23 20:43:59.528: W/dalvikvm(1311): threadid=6: spin on suspend resolved in 1085 msec
08-23 20:43:59.528: D/dalvikvm(1311): Restored policy of 1320 to 0
08-23 20:43:59.528: D/dalvikvm(1311): Restored priority on 1320 to 10
08-23 20:44:02.460: E/JSON Parser(1311): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {"restaurants":[{"restaurantID":1,"restaurantNAME":"CopperChimney"},{"restaurantID":2,"restaurantNAME":"Aroy"},{"restaurantID":3,"restaurantNAME":"MarkBoulevard"},{"restaurantID":4,"restaurantNAME":"Indian"}],"RestaurantTimings":[{"_id":1,"RestaurantTime":"8pm to 11pm"},{"_id":2,"RestaurantTime":"10pm to 12pm"},{"_id":3,"RestaurantTime":"11pm to 9pm"},{"_id":4,"RestaurantTime":"10pm to 5pm"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
08-23 20:44:02.470: W/dalvikvm(1311): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:78)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-23 20:44:02.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     ... 4 more
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311): Activity com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4051f4e8 that was originally added here
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4051f4e8 that was originally added here
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:95)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity$ParsingAsync.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:58)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-23 20:44:04.531: E/WindowManager(1311):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 20:49:02.664: I/Process(1311): Sending signal. PID: 1311 SIG: 9
08-23 21:12:52.021: E/JSON Parser(1350): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {"restaurants":[{"restaurantID":1,"restaurantNAME":"CopperChimney"},{"restaurantID":2,"restaurantNAME":"Aroy"},{"restaurantID":3,"restaurantNAME":"MarkBoulevard"},{"restaurantID":4,"restaurantNAME":"Indian"}],"RestaurantTimings":[{"_id":1,"RestaurantTime":"8pm to 11pm"},{"_id":2,"RestaurantTime":"10pm to 12pm"},{"_id":3,"RestaurantTime":"11pm to 9pm"},{"_id":4,"RestaurantTime":"10pm to 5pm"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
08-23 21:12:52.030: W/dalvikvm(1350): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:78)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-23 21:12:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     ... 4 more
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350): Activity com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4051f950 that was originally added here
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4051f950 that was originally added here
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:95)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity$ParsingAsync.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:58)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-23 21:12:54.300: E/WindowManager(1350):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 21:13:14.790: D/dalvikvm(1350): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 282K, 52% free 2779K/5703K, external 2061K/2137K, paused 672ms
08-23 21:13:18.330: E/JSON Parser(1350): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {"restaurants":[{"restaurantID":1,"restaurantNAME":"CopperChimney"},{"restaurantID":2,"restaurantNAME":"Aroy"},{"restaurantID":3,"restaurantNAME":"MarkBoulevard"},{"restaurantID":4,"restaurantNAME":"Indian"}],"RestaurantTimings":[{"_id":1,"RestaurantTime":"8pm to 11pm"},{"_id":2,"RestaurantTime":"10pm to 12pm"},{"_id":3,"RestaurantTime":"11pm to 9pm"},{"_id":4,"RestaurantTime":"10pm to 5pm"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
08-23 21:13:18.330: W/dalvikvm(1350): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
```

JSON :: `http://54.218.73.244:7002/`

```
{
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "restaurantID": 1,
      "restaurantNAME": "CopperChimney"
    },
    {
      "restaurantID": 2,
      "restaurantNAME": "Aroy"
    },
    {
      "restaurantID": 3,
      "restaurantNAME": "MarkBoulevard"
    },
    {
      "restaurantID": 4,
      "restaurantNAME": "Indian"
    }
  ],
  "RestaurantTimings": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "RestaurantTime": "8pm to 11pm"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "RestaurantTime": "10pm to 12pm"
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "RestaurantTime": "11pm to 9pm"
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "RestaurantTime": "10pm to 5pm"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: just post your response here

Comment: Your json response is a string?

Comment: Please look at the updated question ..... I have even posted the sample URL i am using

Comment: But in getJSONFromUrl() function at last what are you using??

Comment: @ Piyush .......I am using (http://54.218.73.244:7002/ ) in getJSONFromUrl() ...

Comment: @Sky check the edit. although i have not populated listview i have showed how to get the response and parse restaurants array. Modify accordingly and it should work. I hope you can do the rest on your own from here

Comment: @ raghunandan ...... thank you  ...... for guiding me completing this task !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
     HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
     String _response=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity); 
     Log.i("Response",_response);
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
```

To parse i have shown only  how parse `restaurants` array. Similar parse the other jsonarray `RestaurantTimings`.

```
"restaurants": [ // array of restaurants
{                // json object 
  "restaurantID": 1,      // json string
  "restaurantNAME": "CopperChimney" 
},
{
  "restaurantID": 2,
  "restaurantNAME": "Aroy"
},
{
  "restaurantID": 3,
  "restaurantNAME": "MarkBoulevard"
},
{
  "restaurantID": 4,
  "restaurantNAME": "Indian"
}
],

     try
    {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);

     JSONArray jarr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("restaurants");
             // json array restaurants
      for(int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++)
      {
          JSONObject jb = jarr.getJSONObject(i); 
          String id = jb.getString("restaurantID");
          String name = jb.getString("restaurantNAME");
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name, 1000).show(); 
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

Also i see this

```
  Log.i("parsing..", ""+jsonObject.get("student").toString());
  jObj = new JSONArray(jsonObject.get("student").toString());
```

Where is student in the json posted. It looks like you are doing it wrong

Edit :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        new TheTask().execute();
   }
    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,String,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();
            if(result!=null)
            {
                Log.i("Reponse",result);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, 1000).show();
                // do something
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s =getData();
            return s;
        }

        private String getData() {
            String _response = null;
            try
            {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://54.218.73.244:7002/");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             _response =EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            //
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
            JSONArray jarr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("restaurants");
             for(int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++)
             {
                 JSONObject jb = jarr.getJSONObject(i); 
                 String id = jb.getString("restaurantID");
                 String name = jb.getString("restaurantNAME");
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name, 1000).show(); 
             } 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                  e.printStackTrace();  
            }

            return _response;
        }

    }
}
```

Response

```
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732): {
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):   "restaurants": [
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     {
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "restaurantID": 1,
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "restaurantNAME": "CopperChimney"
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     },
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     {
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "restaurantID": 2,
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "restaurantNAME": "Aroy"
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     },
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     {
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "restaurantID": 3,
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "restaurantNAME": "MarkBoulevard"
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     },
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     {
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "restaurantID": 4,
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "restaurantNAME": "Indian"
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     }
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):   ],
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):   "RestaurantTimings": [
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     {
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "_id": 1,
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "RestaurantTime": "8pm to 11pm"
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     },
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     {
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "_id": 2,
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "RestaurantTime": "10pm to 12pm"
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     },
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     {
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "_id": 3,
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "RestaurantTime": "11pm to 9pm"
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     },
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     {
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "_id": 4,
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):       "RestaurantTime": "10pm to 5pm"
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):     }
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732):   ]
08-23 21:44:51.455: I/Reponse(24732): }
```

Comment: @ Raghunandan .... If you dont mind ...can i send you the project doc.... through mail .... can you have a look at it .... since my code too many changes is to be performed ... my code is just simple at as i posted ..... it will help a beginner like me .... i can keep it as a model to progress my learning

Comment: @Sky i am just one person there are many talented developers in the community who can help you for sure. So i think you have a better chance of solving your problem here on SO. But i tried your code and i do get the json response. Give the above a try

Comment: @ Raghunandan .... Ok ... Np.. Thank you for the help.... your tips made me change the parser completely .... so i did some changes for the parser .... i have taken a standard parser for my use ...... i am getting the eror log as i have updated ..... can you look at the updated question ... and update your answer ... Ill take it forward from there... thanks

Comment: what is MainActivtiy.java line 78 something is null

Comment: It is  "for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++)"

Comment: your `json` is null. i suggest you move all your code from jsonparser class to `doInabckground` and remove multiple try blocks have one try and multiple catch blocks.

Comment: Ok ... thanks for all the help ... ill try and do some changes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36121/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-sky)