# sending data as intents to another activity from listview

Tags: android

I have a main activity which onclick sends an url to another activity

How to add condition such that on click of a perticular row i could send a perticular url parsed from the JSON

---

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/";

    private HashMap<Integer, String> TimeMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    List<Item> yourData = new ArrayList<Item>();

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Instantiating ProgressDialog with onCreate method
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        new ParsingAsync().execute();

    }

    private class ParsingAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please Wait", true, false);


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String _response = null;
            try
            {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             _response =EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
            JSONArray first_array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("restaurants");
            JSONArray second_array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("RestaurantTimings");
             for(int i=0;i<first_array.length();i++)
             {
                    JSONObject c = second_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Item item = new Item();

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    int id = c.getInt("_id");
                    String TIME = c.getString("RestaurantTime");
                    item.setTime(TIME);

                    c = first_array.getJSONObject(i);

                    String NAME=c.getString("restaurantNAME");
                    item.setName(NAME);

                    String URL=c.getString("url");
                    item.setUrl(URL);

                    yourData.add(item);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            //TextView timedisplay=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.RestaurantTimeID);


            ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);



            ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.itemlistrow, yourData);
            yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RestaurantDesc.class);
                    i.putExtra("key", "http://54.218.73.244:7002/CopperChimney");
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

### [EDIT]

I tried using

```
i.putExtra("key", yourData.get(position).getUrl());
```

i can get the successfull data onfirst onclick of listview but on second , third ,..... i get below error

**error**

```
08-25 19:14:57.133: D/dalvikvm(332): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 165K, 50% free 2896K/5703K, external 2111K/2137K, paused 107ms
08-25 19:21:47.553: W/dalvikvm(370): threadid=6: spin on suspend #1 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
08-25 19:21:47.553: D/dalvikvm(370): Temporarily moving tid 378 to fg (was 0)
08-25 19:21:47.553: D/dalvikvm(370): Temporarily raised priority on tid 378 (10 -> 0)
08-25 19:21:47.633: W/dalvikvm(370): threadid=6: spin on suspend resolved in 1078 msec
08-25 19:21:47.633: D/dalvikvm(370): Restored policy of 378 to 0
08-25 19:21:47.633: D/dalvikvm(370): Restored priority on 378 to 10
08-25 20:10:30.833: W/dalvikvm(407): threadid=6: spin on suspend #1 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
08-25 20:10:30.833: D/dalvikvm(407): Temporarily moving tid 415 to fg (was 0)
08-25 20:10:30.833: D/dalvikvm(407): Temporarily raised priority on tid 415 (10 -> 0)
08-25 20:10:30.913: W/dalvikvm(407): threadid=6: spin on suspend resolved in 1079 msec
08-25 20:10:30.913: D/dalvikvm(407): Restored policy of 415 to 0
08-25 20:10:30.913: D/dalvikvm(407): Restored priority on 415 to 10
08-25 20:10:35.985: D/dalvikvm(407): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 166K, 50% free 2896K/5703K, external 2111K/2137K, paused 85ms
08-25 20:10:46.523: W/System.err(407): org.json.JSONException: No value for CopperChimney
08-25 20:10:46.773: W/System.err(407):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
08-25 20:10:46.773: W/System.err(407):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
08-25 20:10:46.773: W/System.err(407):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(RestaurantDesc.java:115)
08-25 20:10:46.783: W/System.err(407):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(RestaurantDesc.java:1)
08-25 20:10:46.783: W/System.err(407):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-25 20:10:46.783: W/System.err(407):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-25 20:10:46.783: W/System.err(407):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-25 20:10:46.783: W/System.err(407):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-25 20:10:46.783: W/System.err(407):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-25 20:10:46.783: W/System.err(407):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-25 20:10:46.793: D/AndroidRuntime(407): Shutting down VM
08-25 20:10:46.793: W/dalvikvm(407): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.onPostExecute(RestaurantDesc.java:138)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.onPostExecute(RestaurantDesc.java:1)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-25 20:10:46.813: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 20:10:52.563: I/Process(407): Sending signal. PID: 407 SIG: 9
08-25 20:10:58.774: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(422): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
08-25 20:25:43.273: D/dalvikvm(422): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 160K, 49% free 2880K/5639K, external 2082K/2137K, paused 87ms
08-25 20:25:49.403: W/System.err(422): org.json.JSONException: No value for CopperChimney
08-25 20:25:49.473: W/System.err(422):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
08-25 20:25:49.473: W/System.err(422):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
08-25 20:25:49.483: W/System.err(422):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(RestaurantDesc.java:115)
08-25 20:25:49.483: W/System.err(422):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(RestaurantDesc.java:1)
08-25 20:25:49.483: W/System.err(422):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-25 20:25:49.483: W/System.err(422):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-25 20:25:49.483: W/System.err(422):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-25 20:25:49.493: W/System.err(422):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-25 20:25:49.493: W/System.err(422):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-25 20:25:49.493: W/System.err(422):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-25 20:25:49.493: D/AndroidRuntime(422): Shutting down VM
08-25 20:25:49.503: W/dalvikvm(422): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.onPostExecute(RestaurantDesc.java:138)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.onPostExecute(RestaurantDesc.java:1)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-25 20:25:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 20:26:51.563: W/dalvikvm(481): threadid=6: spin on suspend #1 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
08-25 20:26:51.563: D/dalvikvm(481): Temporarily moving tid 489 to fg (was 0)
08-25 20:26:51.563: D/dalvikvm(481): Temporarily raised priority on tid 489 (10 -> 0)
08-25 20:26:51.643: W/dalvikvm(481): threadid=6: spin on suspend resolved in 1080 msec
08-25 20:26:51.643: D/dalvikvm(481): Restored policy of 489 to 0
08-25 20:26:51.643: D/dalvikvm(481): Restored priority on 489 to 10
08-25 20:27:48.342: D/dalvikvm(481): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 158K, 50% free 2896K/5703K, external 2111K/2137K, paused 134ms
08-25 20:28:07.754: D/dalvikvm(481): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 353K, 44% free 3770K/6727K, external 2458K/3069K, paused 752ms
08-25 20:28:08.203: D/dalvikvm(481): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 44% free 3770K/6727K, external 2458K/3069K, paused 7ms+16ms
08-25 20:28:08.843: W/System.err(481): org.json.JSONException: No value for CopperChimney
08-25 20:28:08.843: W/System.err(481):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
08-25 20:28:08.853: W/System.err(481):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
08-25 20:28:08.883: W/System.err(481):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(RestaurantDesc.java:115)
08-25 20:28:08.883: W/System.err(481):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(RestaurantDesc.java:1)
08-25 20:28:08.913: W/System.err(481):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-25 20:28:08.913: W/System.err(481):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-25 20:28:08.913: W/System.err(481):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-25 20:28:08.923: W/System.err(481):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-25 20:28:08.933: W/System.err(481):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-25 20:28:08.943: W/System.err(481):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-25 20:28:08.943: D/AndroidRuntime(481): Shutting down VM
08-25 20:28:08.943: W/dalvikvm(481): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.onPostExecute(RestaurantDesc.java:138)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.onPostExecute(RestaurantDesc.java:1)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-25 20:28:08.963: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I hope i am clear with my explanation. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: current code is working but .....I am trying to know how to parse a string obtained from JSON response to another activity .... how to define that condition in listview onitemclick

Comment: But your json is already parsed, and it's present in `yourData` variable right?

Comment: Yes ....its in yourData .... but i want to pass a  **String URL** on perticular position click

Comment: Ok, check my answer, you can use that code, to pass the Restaurant url

Comment: @ Sunil ..... please look at my updated question

Comment: @Sky you need to get the item of listview on click of a row and thenuse intents to pass the data.

Comment: @Raghunandan ............ I am using intents to pass the data between the activities .... so to pass the data i used .......... i.putExtra("key", yourData.get(position).getUrl()); ...... insted of just sending single info but im getting the error as i mentioned in question :(

Comment: Can you post the code of `RestaurantDesc` class, the error is there..., or at least your `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` methods

Comment: @Sky what is line 138 `RestaurantDesc.java`?

Comment: please look at the updated question

Comment: @ Raghunandan ......it has for(int i=0; i < first_array.length(); i++)

Comment: @Sky your `first_array` is null that's why you get NPE.

Comment: @Sky you do not have a json array named `CopperChimney` so your `first_array` is null leading to NPE. check my post. refer back to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405786/listview-in-android-while-getting-data-from-a-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments you have NullPointerException at

```
for(int i=0; i < first_array.length(); i++)
```

So `first_array` is null

Why it is null?

```
first_array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("CopperChimney");
```

Your json does not have a json array with name CopperChimney

`restaurants` and `RestaurantTimings` are array.

`{` //represents json object node

`[` //represents json array node

You have

```
{  // json object node
  "restaurants": [ // json array by name restaurants
```

and

```
"RestaurantTimings": [ // json array by name RestaurantTimings
```

So i don't see `CopperChimney` as a json array any where in your json

To parse

One of your restaurants name is CopperChimney

```
  try
    {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);

     JSONArray jarr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("restaurants");
             // json array restaurants
      for(int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++)
      {
          JSONObject jb = jarr.getJSONObject(i); 
          String id = jb.getString("restaurantID");
          String name = jb.getString("restaurantNAME"); // restaurants name
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name, 1000).show(); 
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
           e.printStacktrace();
    }
```

Comment: Yes Raghunandan .... I understood the errors and i did have a mistake in ResaurantDesc .... Thanks for pointing me to right direction ........ actually CopperChimney is the result of the url im passing on click of copperchimney from list view ..... true i need to generalize in one of the answer Raúl Juárez has suggested

Comment: @Sky once you display it in listview on click of listview you need to get the data from that row and then pass using intents. I don't see you doing that

Comment: Your i/p helped ....... As u told i needed to make a common JSON array name ..... i did it .... so go the proper o/p depending on the row selection from list view ... thanks again !

Comment: @Sky ypu are welcome and glad i could point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Change your line

```
i.putExtra("key", "http://54.218.73.244:7002/CopperChimney");
```

With

```
i.putExtra("key", yourData.get(position).getUrl());
```

**EDIT**

Instead of hardcoding `"CopperChimney"`, try passing another extra:

```
i.putExtra("name", yourData.get(position).getName());
```

and in `RestauranDesc` class, use it (remember initialize it the same as your `url` variable:

```
first_array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info .... but please look art my edited question im facing a deadlock

Comment: `first_array` is null, hence the error. Are you hardcoding the string `CopperChimney`? This key only exists in first response. You can add `restaurantNAME` as another extra, and use it there instead of hardcoding

Answer (score 0):

So your question is how to transform data between activities？Just use Bundle or Intent